# Has anyone encountered the same Error while installing ludwig on colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, gmpy, ludwig

I'm getting the below error while installing ludwig on colab. Tried a few things but not able to resolve this.

> ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-klvuqhbh/gmpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-uo0mqy_u/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-klvuqhbh/gmpy/**

```
Collecting ludwig
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/d2/df3890a7582c7fa8642c0d7fbf1b2de55123b7d008d172a77f10fba1ecb6/ludwig-0.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.25 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.29.12)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.19 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image==0.14.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (2.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (4.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow==1.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (3.13)
Collecting gmpy (from ludwig)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/37/2184c13cee81e1dbeaebbb13570195247e73ab2138a3db0c9d2c5347e372/gmpy-1.17.zip
Requirement already satisfied: fastapi in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.33.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic==0.30.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.30)
Requirement already satisfied: uvicorn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-multipart in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: soundfile in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from ludwig) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from h5py>=2.6->ludwig) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0->ludwig) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0->ludwig) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0->ludwig) (2.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0->ludwig) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.19->ludwig) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn->ludwig) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dask[array]>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (0.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (7.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (0.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<1.15.0rc0,>=1.14.0rc0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (0.33.4)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: starlette<=0.12.0,>=0.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from fastapi->ludwig) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses>=0.6; python_version < "3.7" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pydantic==0.30.0->ludwig) (0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets==7.* in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from uvicorn->ludwig) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h11==0.8.* in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from uvicorn->ludwig) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: uvloop==0.12.*; sys_platform != "win32" and sys_platform != "cygwin" and platform_python_implementation != "pypy" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from uvicorn->ludwig) (0.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click==7.* in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from uvicorn->ludwig) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: httptools==0.0.13; sys_platform != "win32" and sys_platform != "cygwin" and platform_python_implementation != "pypy" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from uvicorn->ludwig) (0.0.13)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from soundfile->ludwig) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib>=3.0->ludwig) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from networkx>=1.8->scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.7.3; extra == "array" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from dask[array]>=1.0.0->scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pillow>=4.3.0->scikit-image==0.14.2->ludwig) (0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.1->ludwig) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0->tensorflow==1.14.0->ludwig) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.0->soundfile->ludwig) (2.19)
Skipping bdist_wheel for ludwig, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for gmpy, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: gmpy, ludwig
  **Running setup.py install for gmpy ... error
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-klvuqhbh/gmpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-uo0mqy_u/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-klvuqhbh/gmpy/**
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue. Looks like an issue with gmpy library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been found and addressed in Github, while installer in pipy has not been updated you can build from source. Check this [PR](https://github.com/uber/ludwig/commit/65ca8e762e109ea1cedbc1f666a4a8e9b4781ea1)

Keep an eye for Ludwig 0.2.1 [here](https://pypi.org/project/ludwig/#history)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for providing the solution. I could find one relevant solution in stackoverflow for fixing the gmpy error. After those three pip commands the Ludwig library installs without errors. Will post that link shortly.

Comment: In Colab: `!pip install git+https://github.com/uber/ludwig.git@65ca8e762e109ea1cedbc1f666a4a8e9b4781ea1`